# MaxCounters Codility Challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I've been doing some Codility challenges lately and the [MaxCounters challenge](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/max_counters/) got me stumped:

> You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two
>   possible operations on them:
>
> - *increase(X)* — counter X is increased by 1,
> - *max counter* — all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
>
> A non-empty array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:
>
> - if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
> - if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max counter.
>
> [...]
>   The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.

Below is my solution in Python.  I can't reach 100% on it even though I am pretty confident it is an O(n+m) complexity solution. Codility fails it and says its an O(n*m) complexity solution.

```
def solution(N, A):
    counter = [0] * N
    max_val = 0

    for v in A:

        if v <= N and v >= 1:
            if counter[v-1] < max_val+1:
                counter[v-1] = max_val+1
            else:
                counter[v-1] += 1
        else:
            max_val = max(counter)

    for i in range(len(counter)):
        if counter[i] < max_val:
            counter[i] = max_val

    return counter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of hints, to avoid spoiling the problem.

Hint 1

> What would happen if every entry in `A` were `N + 1`?

Hint 2

> What is the complexity of `max(counter)`?